# Jquery "On click" OR"unbind" not working with php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with Jquery Ajax and php,I am using Ajax in my controller,
I have php loop and inside loop i have "showmore button",I have "ShowMore" button and with "Last Comment"(coming from db),So whenever i click on "ShowMore"
button...its hide and "New comments" and new "ShowMore" button (HTML) is coming as Ajax Resonse
But Problem is whenever i click on first time on "ShowMore" Button then its working and
data (New Comments and show more button) is coming as ajax response but if i click on next time on "ShowMore"(which is coming as Ajax response) then nothing works,I tried with following functions

```
$('.show_more').unbind('click').bind('click', function (e)
```

with above function "second click" not working means "show more button"(which is coming as ajax response) not working
And if tried with following code then multiple times function work/execute

```
$(document).on('click','.show_more',function()
```

Here is my code in loop and my script code,Where i am wrong ? How can i solve this ? Thanks in advance.

```
function fetch()
    {
        $FeedId; (dynamic)
        $FeedData = $this->M_main->GetFeedData(); // getting feed data from database
        foreach($FeedData as $feeds)
            {
                if($feeds['flag']=="feed")
                    {
                        $GetFeedComments = $this->M_main->GetFeedsComment($FeedId);
                        $TotalFeedsComments=$GetFeedComments['TotalRows'];
                        if($TotalFeedsComments>1)
                                {
                                        $Loads='<div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main'.$postID.'">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="fixs" value="'.$postID.'" id="fixs">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="MinValue" value="'.$postID.'" id="MinValue">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="FeedIdd" value="'.$FeedId.'" id="FeedIdd">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="MaxValue" value="'.$postID.'" id="MaxValue">
                                        <span id='.$postID.' data-val='.$postID.' data-status='.$postID.' class="show_more" title="Load more posts" data-feds='.$FeedId.'>Show more</span>
                                        <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
                                                            </div>';
                                }
                        
                    }
            }
    $pathss= base_url()."Main/GetFeedCommentsById"; 
             echo "
                <script>
                $('.show_more').unbind().click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
                        var vals=$(this).data('val');
                        var feds=$(this).data('feds');
                        $('.show_more').hide();
                    $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url:'".$pathss."',
                            data:{id:ID, vals:vals},
                            success:function(html){
                                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                                $('.postList'+feds).append(html);
                            }
                        });
                    
                    });
                </script>
                ";
```

Comment: The JavaScript needs to be loaded into your main page (i.e. not via Ajax) and stay there. It should not be part of the Ajax response (it's not clear from your snippet above whether it is or not)

Comment: @ADyson: As i mentioned both function working "unbind" and "click" but problems with both , means if i use "unbind" then working one time only and if i use "click" then working more than one time, I just want to use one time and will work again one time whenever i click on button , Thats it

Comment: Write your java script code inside    $(document).ready(function() { })

Comment: @Pramodkushwaha: means i have to write "documen ready" ...and put code between this ?

Comment: @Nisha I understood all that. That's why I gave my advice. Did you try it?

Comment: @ADyson: Sorry but not understand your point, can you explain or write correct code so i can check properly

Comment: Well it's simple - where is your Javascript code located? Is it part of the page which is loaded initially by normal request, or is it part of the response coming from AJAX (and thus being loaded again every time you click load more)? It's more the position of your code in the application I was asking about, rather than its correctness. Since your code sample is incomplete it's hard to tell exactly what is going on. It would helpn us if you could provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: @ADyson: You are right , its "it part of the response coming from AJAX (and thus being loaded again every time you click load more) "...

Comment: Ok. You should place it into the main part of the page. That should help a lot.

Comment: @Adson : "main part of page" ? means ?

Comment: yes, put your code between $(document).ready(function() { })

Comment: @Pramodkushwaha: with "Unbind" or "click" function ?

Comment: @Nisha yes with "Unbind" or "click" function

Comment: @Pramodkushwaha: Tried but facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are removing the html node on ajax success message, and the event listener goes away.

You should add the listener again to the new node;

```
<script>
// Assign the event listener to a variable, to reuse it
let myEventListenerFunction = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var vals=$(this).data('val');
        var feds=$(this).data('feds');
        $('.show_more').hide();
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'".$pathss."',
            data:{id:ID, vals:vals},
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.postList'+feds).append(html);
                // Add event to a new node
                $('.show_more').unbind().click(myEventListenerFunction);
            }
        });
    
}
$('.show_more').unbind().click(myEventListenerFunction);
</script>
```

Comment: Still same , actually my problem with "click" or "Unbind", its working oen time only or multiple times

Comment: without append "previous" data not working

Comment: I rewrite the answer, because the idea was correct, but the problem was on the inner node, that will be rewritten anyway. On the ajax success, you should add the event again

Comment: second click is not working with your code

Comment: The new html code contains the nodes with correct names and classes?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: I changed the way to bind the event on ajax response. Now will re-bind all elements with class `show_more` on the page. If this doesn't work, I need an example of ajax responde (I only need the html tags, and you can delete the text content, unless the text contains special html charactes like `<` and/or `>`, that will cause an invalid HTML)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238713/discussion-between-manuel-romeiro-and-nisha).

Answer (score 0):

There are some problem with your code but if you just want to make it work as it is the best way in my opinion is to separate the javascript part from the rest.
One way to achieve that is to add this script in your page into a separate js file

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.show_more',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                        var $self = $(this);
                        var ID = $self.attr('id');
                        var vals=$self.data('val');
                        var feds=$self.data('feds');
                        $('.show_more').hide();
                        var url = $self.data('url');
                        
                    $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url: url,
                            data:{id:ID, vals:vals},
                            success:function(html){
                                $self.remove();
                                $('.postList'+feds).append(html);
                            }
                        });
                    
                    });
</script>
```

And in the php part you have to had one attribute like this

```
$Loads='<div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main'.$postID.'" data-url="'.$pathss.'">...</div>';
```